# Is there a way I could find a matlab or R code to estimate a regime switching stochastic volatility model (discrete)?

Tags: volatility, stochastic, markov-switching

Sorry to bother you with this request but, does anyone know where I could find a matlab or R code to estimate a regime switching stochastic volatility model (discrete)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hae you tried R-bloggers?

Comment: Yes I have. But nothing. I only found a code for Winbugs but it uses particle filters. I was looking for something more lets say traditional. I would also be interésted in finding a code for AR(1) bayesian markov switching in mean.